# How to access functions passed in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have written a simple javascript function to generate pie/donut chart. I cannot use any chart library available in the market. I am struck at writing legend click event. 
I am passing the chart parameters as javascript object

```
{
 chartType:"donut", 
 legend: {
            click: function() { "legendText" // create another chart based on this value. }
           }
}
```

In the click function based on the legend value, user will write a second javascript object object for generating another donut chart(I am planning to ask the user to use legendText, which will get the legend text on click).
The main trouble this how to include this user function in my legendclick event and how to determine the selected legend code

```
behind(legenditem.addeventlistener("click",function(){})).
```

Comment: JSON is not usually used to store these things, its a data exchange. However, you can always stringify a function and then start it using the Function constructor, although it might create potential attack vectors if anyone is allowed to add functions like that...

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON cannot express functions. What you have is a simple *Javascript object.*

Comment: @deceze: Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: @deceze: I have update my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I should have tried this before posting.
User:

```
{
  legend:{
          click : function(legendSelectedText){
                 //do your operations
           }
  }
}
```

Chart Function:

```
legenditem.addEventListener("click",function(){
   var legenditem = //get legendtext from code behind;
   chartObject.legend.click(legenditem);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a new function and running it.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(yourstring);
var func = new Function(obj.MyFunction);
func();
```

Note: Your function must be in string format, not code format for this to work. Although this poses some security risks.